# Site for NZ and AU appearing in the US search results over the site for the US

Tags: seo, google-search-console, multiple-domains, geotargeting

I have 2 websites, one for Australia and New Zealand, and another for the US and the rest of the world the one for the Australia is indexing 1st when I search it from the US, how can I promote the US site and remove the Australian site from the US index

Comment: You can't have a site for two countries.  To be able to geo-target your site and not have it not appear in the US search results you need to focus it on just one country.   Create a site for AU and a second site for NZ.   Then set the geo targeting for each of them in Google Search Console.   The sites can be completely 100% duplicate.  They just need different domains or subdomains.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller You can target a page or site to multiple countries with hreflang, e.g., you could have `.com/north-america/`targeted to `"en-us"` and `"en-ca"` [source: https://twitter.com/JohnMu/status/837326127089729536?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.rebelytics.com%2Fmultiple-hreflang-tags-one-url%2F]. Of course, this approach only helps Google and Yandex.

Answer (score 2):

Use [hreflang](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en) to target the two sites to their respective markets. This markup is supported by Google and Yandex, but not Bing etc., which may or may not be an issue depending on your traffic sources.

Google's John Mueller has [confirmed](https://twitter.com/JohnMu/status/837326127089729536?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.rebelytics.com%2Fmultiple-hreflang-tags-one-url%2F) that the same content can be targeted to multiple markets, and I've had clients successfully deploy this approach. For example:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.example.com/oceania/" hreflang="en-au">
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.example.com/oceania/" hreflang="en-nz">
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.example.com/us/" hreflang="en-us">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you think, plan and implement 2 different sites with unique content and structure then you do not need to worry which one getting indexed first.

Let's say you have got:

- example-au-nz.com
- example-us.com

Now, your business process may be same but its highly recommended that you should have unique content, website structure etc for both websites.

On a side note: If your website structure (Design, Navigation etc) may be same (to save cost etc) then you should even be more careful about unique content on the website.

**Modified:**

Watch This: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ets7nHOV1Yo

Now, even if there will be same content on different TLDs which may be OK but no one can guarantee the level of duplication Google will detect.

My approach would be simple, if a business just need websites in different countries (Different TLDs) without expecting much results then I would say it would be OK.

But as an when you plan and think about greater ranking, my approach would be GO UNIQUE. Safe and effective approach.

We can see all big companies when they have the significant local operation they have unique design tailored to a local audience with appropriate text.

So, sometimes grey book theory is not good enough.

Examples:
Let's say: Oracle website US & AU might have duplicate content on the same domain. As their website is not targeted to the normal consumer.

Another example ebay (US and AU) got different domain and they do rely on organic traffic and hence they have different content & structure. Same applies to Gumtree etc.

**Conclusion**

My approach would be to implement clean and safer techniques. Things which we don't know how Google may consider duplicate content it's always better to be safe.

Comment: Having completely different content is hard.  It is also not needed.   Google lets you have duplicate sites focused on different countries.  They even end up ranking better than a globally targeted site.

Comment: This is quite grey. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ets7nHOV1Yo
TLDs have mentioned. Firstly, there are many businesses which operate in AU and NZ using one website. Sorry, don't agree as without knowing details. Unique content is by far the best and risk-free method.

Comment: Right or wrong... I could not stand seeing -2 on one of your answers. Cheers!! I am not sure what is objectionable, perhaps an edit is required. I know you give good answers! So I am sure it is minor.

Comment: Appreciate your feedback. Just added few extra lines. If someone downvote, it will be good not just comment (General one line) but also have a detailed answer with appropriate link/reference. Now, if the subject matter is bit grey like above, it might need an answer with some examples.